# Doctrine How to extend custom repository and call the extended repository from doctrine entity manager

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to know how to extend a custom repository and call the extended repository from doctrine entity manager in doctrine.

My Entity class :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Vendor\MyBundle\Repository\MyEntityRepository")
*/
class MyEntity 
{
...
```

My Entity Repository class:

```
class MyEntityRepository extends EntityRepository
{
 ...
```

My Extended Repository class:

```
class MyExtendedEntityRepository extends MyEntityRepository
{
 ...
```

Call of MyEntityRepository:

```
class MyEntityManager
{
    protected $emr;

    /**
     *
     * @return MyEntityRepository
     */
     public function getRepository()
     {
          return $this->emr->getRepository('MyVendorBundle:MyEntity');
     }
 ...
```

Call of MyExtendedEntityRepository?

```
class MyOtherEntityManager
{
    protected $emr;

    /**
     *
     * @return MyExtendedEntityRepository
     */
     public function getRepository()
     {
         //This is what i want to know: How to access to the extended repository?
     }
 ...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, doctrine getRepository() works with the entity and resolve the repository related. I does not understand what is the logical or use case, but if you need reuse some part of repository throw other entities its recommended the use of traits. In the other hand if you really need use that scenario you can simply build `MyExtendedEntityRepository` in the `getRepository` method.

```
/**
 *
 * @return MyExtendedEntityRepository
 */
 public function getRepository()
 {
   $class = $this->emr->getClassMetadata(MyEntity::class);
   return new MyExtendedEntityRepository($this->emr, $class);
 }
```

Comment: It works!. The use case is that if an optionable bundle is enabled it has to make specific queries reusing extended repository methods of a required bundle. With this solution no need to add manually trait when  the optionable bundle is enabled.