# How to extend repositories in Doctrine 2? for share common functionalities in different table names?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.3

I have been doing some research on this topic but so far I couldn't find anything helpful for my scenario.

In a brief: I have two tables `Quote` (table name: quote) and `QuoteArchive` (table name: quote_archive). Both share exactly the same columns and types. As far as I have read this turn into a [Doctrine MappedSuper Class](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses) ex: `MappedSuperclassQuote`.

After that `Quote` and `QuoteArchive` entities will extend from the `MappedSuperclassQuote` and both will share exactly the same structure.

`Quote` has a custom Repository with some functions. `QuoteArchive` needs exactly the same Repository functions as in `Quote` with the only difference being the table name and the PK.

I have two doubts in this scenario:

- How to extend Doctrine entities when the PK (@Id) is different in the child classes?
- How to extend or share the same repository between entities when the only change is the table name.

For get a better idea this is how my current entities looks like:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="quote")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="QuoteBundle\Entity\Repository\QuoteRepository")
 */
class Quote
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer",unique=true,nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $quoteId;

    // ...
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="quote_archive")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="QuoteBundle\Entity\Repository\QuoteArchiveRepository")
 */
class QuoteArchive
{   
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer",unique=true,nullable=false)
     */
    private $archiveId;

    // ...
}
```

Last but not least:

```php
class QuoteRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getCurrentQuoteId(int $OrigQuoteId)
    {
        $em   = $this->getEntityManager();
        $qb   = $em->createQueryBuilder();

        return $qb->select('q')
                  ->from('QuoteBundle:Quote')
                  ->where('q.origQuoteId =:origQuoteId')
                  ->setParameter('origQuoteId', $OrigQuoteId)
                  ->andWhere('q.quoteType =:quoteType')
                  ->setParameter('quoteType', 'current')
                  ->getQuery()
                  ->getResult();
    }
}
```

What is the problem here? I need to repeat the same exact function in `QuoteArchiveRepository` and change the table from `quote` to `quote_archive` and it's exactly what I am trying to avoid if possible.

Can any give me some ideas? Code example would be great :)

References:

- [Can we extend entities in Doctrine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904057/can-we-extend-entities-in-doctrine)
- [Doctrine: extending entity class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8943615/doctrine-extending-entity-class)
- [Doctrine How to extend custom repository and call the extended repository from doctrine entity manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43793101/doctrine-how-to-extend-custom-repository-and-call-the-extended-repository-from-d)

Comment: Two different types of entities can actually share the exact same repository class.

Comment: @Cerad yes, I could make them to use the same Repository class but that won't fix my issue

Comment: Are you at all familiar with dql?

Comment: @Cerad not an expert but yes I am familiar with it

Comment: In that case, adjust your query to use dql and the need for the table name goes away.  You might also research a bit on prepared statements.

Comment: @Cerad I am not seeing how the table name will go away either way I need to specify the Entity name in the `from()` unless your though is to pass it as a parameter on the function and bind it to the DQL, is that?

Comment: I thought you said you were familiar with DQL?  Research a bit on how to do queries with a doctrine repository.  Hint:  A repository is already bound to an entity type.  You are making this much harder then it has to be,

Comment: @Cerad I've modified my sources to use QB instead of DQL but either way I am not seeing how it would help me. I've re-read the [docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) again and no matter what I need to specify the entity I  am querying. At the end I am still issuing the same problem, isn't? Can you add an answer showing your thoughts?

Comment: $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('q') ... And if you really want a chuckle then take a look at $repo->findBy(['origQuoteId' => $origQuoteId, 'quoteType' => 'current']);

Answer (score 2):

I think you're mistaking doing a MappedSuperclassQuote entity.
You have to inherit the Archive from the Quote.

Example : you have your Quote entity
The definition should be something like :

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_quote")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="quote_type", fieldName="quoteType", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *     "quote":"YourBundle\Entity\Quote",
 *     "quote_archive":"YourBundle\Entity\QuoteArchive"
 * })
 * @Gedmo\Loggable
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="YourBundle\Repository\QuoteRepository")
 */
```

Why a JOINED inheritance ? Cause you want two separate tables (what SINGLE_TABLE is not doing) and you don't have a really abstract class (cause Quote AND QuoteArchive means something for you)

After, your table QuoteArchive should extends the first one :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_quote_archive")
 */
class QuoteArchive extends Quote
{
...
}
```

Your column quote_type in app_quote will help you to know if this is an archived quote or not.

It provides you all you want :
- QuoteArchive will have access to functions inside QuoteRepository
- Each table has separated ids

One thing could be annoying for you : if you want to set a quote has archived, it's not so easy to change an entity type for now in Doctrine. In that case, it's better for you to use single_table joining type. All the datas are stored in a same table in database, making type change easy but you keep two different entities.

Comment: Wow! This is a great answer however is not quite what I need. Why? Cause I don't need to access `QuoteRepository` from `QuoteArchive`. What I do need is change the table name dinamically, see the edit on the OP so you get a better understanding from my current issue and see if your answer still help in such case.